# Declare main() as friend function in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class that I only wish clients create them one object per process. Instead of singleton, a better way (I believe) is to tell the clients to only create them in main(). So a natural enforcement is to make the constructor private and main() as a friend.

It works this way:

```
class A { friend int main(int, char**); A() {} };
int main(int, char **) { A a; }
```

But it breaks when I need to put class A in a namespace:

```
namepace ns { class A { friend int main(int, char**); A() {} }; }
int main(int, char **) { ns::A a; }
```

The problem is scoping: the compiler now thinks

```
friend int main
```

means a function named main() in namespace ns. So the real main() becomes irrelevant.

So the question is: how to fix this? Of course I'll have to put class A in a namespace.

Comment: Making main a friend has completely different semantics than one object per process: having main as a friend does not prevent it from creating more than one object. otoh, one object per process could well mean that object is accessible in other functions that just in main(). So what do you *really* want to accomplish? What's your class about?

Comment: Why is that a better way?

Comment: I don't think `friend` does what you think it does.

Comment: int main(int, char **) { ns::A a, b,c,d; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare `main` in the global namespace before the class definition, since `friend` declarations can only introduce names in the surrounding namespace:

```
int main(int, char**);
```

and qualify the name when referring to it inside the namespace:

```
namepace ns { class A { friend int ::main(int, char**); A() {} }; }
//                                 ^^
```

Answer (score 5):

Use "`::`" to qualify something as being in the global namespace, i.e.:

```
friend int ::main(int argc, char** argv);
```

Comment: What do I have to do if I want to do this in a library?